# Why is uuid property set in Spring JUnit test?

Tags: java, spring, junit4, spring-test

I noticed that in a JUnit test with Spring context property uuid always exists and has a specific value. What is the value and why it exists at all?
There are no properties files in my project, and the `PropertyPlaceHolderConfigurer` defined in the only spring context read by the test is empty, it doesn't load any properties.

My test class:

```
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "classpath:main-context.xml"
})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
public class MyTest {

    @Value("${uuid}") String uuidProp;

    @Test
    public void test() {
        System.out.println("uuid = " + uuidProp);
        System.out.println("uuid sys property = " + System.getProperty("uuid"));
    }
}
```

main-context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

    <bean class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    </bean>
</beans>
```

This always prints out the same values.

Comment: I'm not sure what your question is, did you write this code?

Comment: Yes, this is a junit test that just starts this simple context with an empty PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer and shows that uuid property exists even though it's not defined anywhere

Comment: Are you using Spring Boot? And please add which spring version you use.

Comment: Test fails with me, so it must be set somewhere in your environment, Either as a test variable environment or system variable. There is also `System.getenv()` which you can try. Else inject the `Environment` and do a `getProperty` on it (turn on debugging) and see where it comes from.

Comment: You were right. it was defined in my environment properties.